# SharePoint Online Custom modern page Footer using Application Customizer

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

We are creating a custom footer though SPFx Application Customizer for modern sharepoint pages. But our requirement on the Footer is to show the footer with a increased height. Once we deployed the customizer the Body of the page is not fully displayed. The footer is getting freeze in the screen and the rest of the body content needed to navigate via vertical scrolls. The code block to set the footer is mentioned below.

```
 let bottomPlaceholder: PlaceholderContent = this.context.placeholderProvider.tryCreateContent(PlaceholderName.Bottom);

    if (bottomPlaceholder) {
      ServiceManagerStatic.getService().getFooterContent("").then((footer)=>{
        console.log(footer);
        bottomPlaceholder.domElement.innerHTML = footer;
      }).catch((err)=>{

      });    
    return Promise.resolve();
```

Ideally the Footer should be placed in the bottom of the page not in the bottom of the screen. Is there a solution to apply this footer in bottom of the page so that it won't affect the contents of the page?

Comment: Try updating your SPFx version -- I'm seeing no cutoff with spfx 1.5: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki

Comment: @Kanishka did you get it figured out? I don't want to go through the trouble if it's still a sticky / window footer

Answer (score 0):

@kanishka - Did you manage to find the solution - I have a similar requirement where custom footer only needs to be visible when user scrolls down bottom of the page. We tried to set the placeholder position absolute but there are multiple scrollbars appearing. Any help highly appreciated !!

Comment: @Ashwani...post a new question rather than asking question in answer....

Comment: Sorry, But I try to put a comment rather than posting a question because I have similar issue. I can't comment to above post as it says 50 reputation required.